# Pandas None logical indexing confusion

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am a relatively new user of pandas.
And I can't understand why the code works this way.
Why it returns True when the element is actually equal to None?

```
In [14]:
import pandas as pd
tweets = pd.DataFrame([None, None], columns=['country'])
print tweets['country'] != None

Out[14]:
0    True
1    True
Name: country, dtype: bool
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: You should be doing `tweets['country'].notnull()` I don't think this comparison would work like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, this happens because pandas considers `None` to be largely equivalent to `NaN`, and `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`. As @economy and others have said, use the `isnull()` or `notnull()` methods to do what you'd like.

Now, some justification for why this isn't a bug. The equality operator is defined by the Cython code found in `pandas.lib`. Specifically, `pandas.lib.scalar_compare` is invoked when you write `tweets['country'] == None`. Notice how `scalar_compare` works:

```
>>> pd.lib.scalar_compare(np.array([None]), None, operator.ne)
array([ True], dtype=bool)
```

That's the behavior you're seeing. Now, it's not likely this is a bug, because if we look at the [code for `scalar_compare`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/7da9178dad2c4b000c2446e5cc58ff0613a631c1/pandas/lib.pyx#L681-L685), it points us to a [`_checknull` function](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d94dd2ada7d0af57c245b083d26d60b8649a04e/pandas/src/util.pxd#L68-L72) which explicitly handles `None`. If we look at that code, we see that it essentially (and very deliberately) says that `None == None` is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the expression is returning true, but you can use pandas built in null checker to determine whether values are null:

```
print tweets.notnull()

country
0   False
1   False
```

The counterpart is

```
print tweets.isnull()

country
0   True
1   True
```